# Python 3.6: Why does pickle.dumps(nparray) permanently increase refcount?

Tags: python, numpy, automatic-ref-counting

An np.ndarray, when pickled, increments reference counter from the dumps function, however the ref count is never decremented.

Python 3.6.4 Anaconda
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
numpy 1.16.0

I have already tried converting to a list using numpy.array.tolist() however this method is far too slow.

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys

a = np.ndarray((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
print(sys.getrefcount(a)) # 2
pickle.dumps(a)
print(sys.getrefcount(a)) # 3
```

I would expect the output to be 2, 2 due to the Py_DECREF that occurs in the pickler dumps function, however it remains.

Output is 2, 3 and I cannot fix it. I am leaking memory like crazy.

Currently digging into _pickle.c.

Comment: `frame` is just rather bog-standard `numpy.ndarray()` instance. Can you reproduce this issue without `cv2` and just with, say, `frame = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)`?

Comment: Also, what exact version of Python 3.6 is this, and what OS is this on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am on Python 3.6.8 Anaconda ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I will try to reproduce with np.zeros. Thanks for the advice! Will comment again with results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was able to reproduce with just np.zeros. Numpy refcount increments without ever decrementing. This even ocurrs with ndarray.dumps()

Comment: right, so we are getting somewhere a little simpler. Can you update your question? You may want to consider filing a bug report with the numpy project, however.

Comment: Of course! I'll publish a bug report ASAP.

Comment: Okay so it isn't just a CPython problem. Most likely coming from the numpy C implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into [this specific bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12793), and it's a regression in Numpy 1.16.0 only. New code to add support for [a new pickle protocol 5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/) was leaking references to a bound `__reduce__` method in the fallback case.

You can either wait for that bug to be fixed and 1.16.1 to be released, or go back to Numpy 1.15.4.